# How to see publisher logs from browser in AEM?

Tags: aem

How to see publisher logs from browser ?

I tried with "http://localhost:4503/bin/crxde/logs?tail=1000".
But i didn't get logs. Is there any way to enable this?

Comment: version of AEM matters. the url has changed since aem 6.2

Comment: But I could see author logs with same url with port 4502

Comment: but you were logged in and on publish probably not?

Comment: yes . thanks now I am able to see.

Comment: also mind that the servlet is available iff the CRXDE bundle is turned on for the publish instance. For the security purpose that often is disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just go to crx/de and see them by going to `console` tab and unclicking `stop`

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Use this

http://localhost:4503/system/console/slinglog/tailer.txt?tail=600&name=/logs/error.log

Change error.log to other file as needed.